# Show all data with class same as the id clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about Jquery.
I want to show all data with the same class as I clicked on.

i made a list of things I can click on. So when I click it, the right data should be shown. I made this but it's not working.

This is my Jquery code:

```
$("div span").hide();
$('input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function(e) {

    var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
    if(this.checked){
        alert("checked");
        e.preventDefault();

    }else{
        alert("not checked");
    }


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8k7ad9pg/

Comment: It works as it should work. When you click, it says clicked and when unchecked, it says not checked.

Comment: where have you added class??

Comment: the alerts are just to help me. I tried some code to show the data with the same ID but deleted it cause it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("div span").hide();
$('input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
    if(this.checked){
        $("." + id).show();
    }else{
        $("." + id).hide();
    }
});
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8k7ad9pg/1/q**